# How do I check checkboxes using only a keyboard?

Tags: freebsd, input-method

How can I check the check boxes in an install wizard using only a keyboard? I have tried every conceivable keyboard command. <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> etc.

Comment: did you try space?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check checkboxes using <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> in most of the interfaces.

<sup>I would rather write an answer than to close this question as off-topic (in which queue I found it), because there is nothing wrong in it.</sup>